# Force user to Set Passcode and Screen Timeout in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

**Targetting iOS 8 with Monotouch**

When our app starts up on iOS I would like to check that the user has set a Passcode (at least) and a screen timeout of no more than 3 minutes.

If they have not I want to Force them to go to Settings and do so. Is this possible?

It is possible for Android apps with Admin permissions

Answer (score 2):

Try this out :)

https://github.com/liamnichols/UIDevice-PasscodeStatus

Once you've added the category you can check it like so:

```
- (void)checkPasscodeState
{
    LNPasscodeStatus status = [UIDevice currentDevice].passcodeStatus;
    switch (status) {
        case LNPasscodeStatusEnabled:
            // a passcode is set 
            break;

        case LNPasscodeStatusDisabled:
            // passcode is not set
            break;

        case LNPasscodeStatusUnknown:
        default:
            // error checking.. fallback somehow.
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if this is for an enterprise app and you have an MDM system, you could use a configuration profile to require that a passcode is set on the device.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that the user has a passcode, you can attempt storing an item in the Keychain with `kSecAttrAccessible` set to `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly`. Then you can verify that it exists and indirectly verify that the user has a passcode.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are currently not able to get the information about password and screen auto-lock delay time.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this only by MDM in ios device where we can directly enforce this.
For Android as you said this could be achieved in may ways